# Camel Redis Component subscribe to a channel not working

Tags: redis, apache-camel, publish-subscribe, spring-data

I've a simple route that listens to a Redis channel. For some reason it's not working. 
Here is my route. I verified that data is being published into the Redis channel and I can read it back using a normal Jedis subscriber. I'm running Camel inside Jetty and it is deployed as a war.

```
public class RedisSubscriberRoute extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("spring-redis://localhost:6379?command=SUBSCRIBE&channels=mychannel") 
    .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String res = exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();
                System.out.println("************ " + res); 
                exchange.getOut().setBody(res);
            }
        })
    .to("log:foo");
}
```

}

**UPDATE (10-May-2013 9:56 AM EST): Adding version information**

```
    <properties>
            <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <camel.version>2.11.0</camel.version>
            <jetty.version>7.6.8.v20121106</jetty.version>
    </properties>
```

**Redis server version is 2.6.11**

The sample git project is here. 
https://github.com/soumyasd/camelredisdemo

**UPDATE 10-May-2013 (10:18 PM EST):**

As suggested in the comments below I changed the version of the spring-data to 1.0.0.RELEASE. Looks like the message is getting to the subscriber but I'm still getting an exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 77686174
    at org.apache.camel.component.redis.RedisConsumer.onMessage(RedisConsumer.java:73)[camel-spring-redis-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:242)[spring-data-redis-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.processMessage(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:231)[spring-data-redis-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$DispatchMessageListener$1.run(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:726)[spring-data-redis-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_45]
```

Comment: Which version of Camel and Redis are you using?

Comment: I've update the question with version information as well as link to the a demo project on github.

Comment: For the time being, can you try change the drive version in camel-spring-redis component as follow:  
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Thanks. I changed the version and looks like something is working. However, I'm still getting an exception. Please see my "update 2" above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something broken in the consumer with v 1.0.3.RELEASE, use 1.0.0.RELEASE instead.

The exception you are getting is something different: Camel producer uses Spring RedisTemplate, which in turn uses JdkSerializationRedisSerializer. To make it symetric, the consumer by default also uses JdkSerializationRedisSerializer to deserialize data. So if you are using Camel producer to publish data, it should work fine w/o hustle. But if you are publishing data to redis using other redis clients (or as in your case some other libraries) you have to use another serializer for the consumer. Long explanation, but to make it work is actually two lines:

from("spring-redis://localhost:6379?command=SUBSCRIBE&channels=mychannel&serializer=#serializer")

Comment: I'm using Jedis (and a Python (redis-py) to publish to the Redis channel. So I need to add this serializer in my spring XML. Let me try .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary of what I had to change to make this work.

1. As pointed out by @Bilgin Ibryam - you have to use the version 1.0.0.RELEASE of spring-data-redis (as on 11-May-2013)

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
                   <!-- IMPORTANT - as of 10-May-2013 the Redis Camel
                        component only works with version 1.0.0.RELASE -->
       <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Other versions that I used in my [pom.xml](https://github.com/soumyasd/camelredisdemo/blob/master/pom.xml) are

   3.2.2.RELEASE
           2.11.0
           7.6.8.v20121106
3. If you are publishing and consuming using the Camel Redis component you don't have to declare a different serializer. In my case I was publishing from python as well as plain old Java using Jedis. I had to [change as my route](https://github.com/soumyasd/camelredisdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/redis/RedisSubscriberRoute.java) to include the serializer and define the serializer in my [spring/camel config](https://github.com/soumyasd/camelredisdemo/blob/master/src/main/resources/camel-config.xml).

   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {

   ```
   from("spring-redis://localhost:6379?command=SUBSCRIBE&channels=mychannel&serializer=#redisserializer") 
   .process(new Processor() {
           @Override
           public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
               String res = exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();
               System.out.println("************ " + res); 
               exchange.getOut().setBody(res); 
           }
       })
   .to("log:foo");
   ```

   }

Comment: There is a 1.0.4 release of spring-data-redis. Do you you mind testing that release?

Comment: I tried with 1.0.4.RELEASE of spring-data-redis and it still doesn't work. No sure where the issue is.

Comment: btw that has been fixed on trunk now